# Sencha Touch- Can´t I instantiate (as an item) the same panel for two different panels?

Tags: sencha-touch, panel, instantiation

I have this panel

```
Mobz.views.aPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'apanel ',
    tpl: aPanel _Template,
    data: Mobz.stores.aPanel _Store
});
```

I'm trying to use it in two diferent panels, and I cannot. Sencha will treat only the last call\instantiation.

Example for instantiation

```
Mobz.views.IngressoTipo = new Ext.Container({
    id: 'ingressostipo',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [Mobz.views.aPanel]
});
```

Can someone please help me to see how to reuse the same object, in multiple panels? I want to duplicate my code.

Thanks for any help!!!
Shlomi.

Comment: why can't you add the item dynamcally and remove it after use...

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up! I'll try investigating in that matter.

Comment: @heyjii, try posting your comment as an answer, and I'll approve your help as the answer for my question. This way you'll get the rank you deserves to :)

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked for you... I will post it as an answer.        Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reuse a panel as an item in multiple containers, you can add it add it dynamically and remove it after use with **add()** and **remove()** methods ie

```
yourParentPanel.add(childPanel);

yourParentPanel.remove(childPanel);
```